# Get & set caret position in contentEditable iframe (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've successfully done this for IE7. FF, no dice.

any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var range= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
alert('Current position: '+range.startOffset+' inside '+range.startContainer);
range.setStart(newParent, textOffset);
range.setEnd(newParent, textOffset);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution to the OpenWYSIWYG for moving the cursor to a specified position in FireFox, after setting focus to the editor:

```
focusEditor: function (n) {
    var editor = this.getEditorWindow(n);

    if (WYSIWYG_Core.isFF) {

        editor.document.body.focus();

        try {
            var sel = this.getSelection(n);
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode.childNodes[0], 1);
            range.setEnd(sel.anchorNode.childNodes[0], 0);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
        catch (err) {
            //alert(err.description);
        }
    }
},
```